# dump an object in ejs templates from express3.x views?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using ejs templates with node.js and express 3.x...is it possible to dump a data object passed into view?

Something like this in index.ejs:

```
<%= dump(session) %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define `dump` and any other functions for use in views with [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals):

```
app.locals.dump = function () {
    // ...
};
```

One option for this could be to expose [`util.format()`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format) or [`util.inspect()`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors):

```
app.locals.inspect = require('util').inspect;
```

Then:

```
<pre><%= inspect(session) %></pre>
```